# Drupal 7 - Display image in place of taxonomy term

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-taxonomy, drupal-content-types

I have added an image field to a vocab. This allows me to create a new term and associate an image with that term.

When I create a new content type I want to add a Term Reference field but display the image and not the term.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use:

https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_image
or also templating the content type you can put the image into the description or a new field into taxonomy and use taxonomy therm page at the display.
Regards.